# How do I read this question? (subject: bijections)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

## Introduction

In *Basic Algebra I*, I am struggling with *fully* understanding the following exercise:

> Show that $S\overset{\alpha}{\to}T$ is injective if and only if there is a map $T\overset{\beta}{\to}S$ such that $\beta\alpha=1_S$, surjective if and only if there is a map $T\overset{\beta}{\to}S$ such that $\alpha\beta=1_T$. **In both cases, investigate the assertion: if $\beta$ is unique then $\alpha$ is bijective.**

## My Problem

I am struggling only with the bold portion. (I have written proofs by contradiction for the other aspects of the question.) What confuses me specifically is this:

- What is this question really asking? Is it saying, "What happens when $\beta$ is unique when both $\beta\alpha=1_S$ *and* $\alpha\beta=1_T$?" **or** is it saying, "What happens when $\beta$ is unique and either $\beta\alpha=1_S$ *or* $\alpha\beta=1_T$ is true?"

## Remarks

As you can see, my real problem here is understanding precisely what is being asked. If it is asking, the first (both $\alpha\beta=1_T$ and $\beta\alpha=1_S$ are true), then we're simply constructing the very definition of a bijection. If it's asking the latter, I don't know what's going on . . . Are we somehow still constructing a bijection?

Can you all give me help on reading questions such as this?

Comment: That an injective map has a left inverse is only true if its domain is nonempty.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I agree mainly, but there is one exception. An injective map also has a left-inverse if its domain and codomain are *both* empty.

Comment: @drhab Point taken.

Comment: See the posts linked to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553186/left-inverse-iff-injective-right-inverse-iff-surjective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I parse this as follows:

The bold sentence refers *separately* to each of the two statements.

So expanded out, this would be:

1a.  Show that ... is injective if and only if ...  Show **also** that if $\beta$ is unique then $\alpha$ is bijective.

1b.  Show that ... is surjective if and only if...  Show **also** that if $\beta$ is unique then $\alpha$ is bijective.

Comment: Why do you parse this this way? Why is this correct when the other interpretation is not? I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm genuinely asking those questions because I don't see why this is the intended meaning of the question.

Comment: Fair question.  I replace 'both' with 'each', where the claim is that the statement "in both cases" is true iff "each case" is true separately.

Comment: Could you explain what the mathematical consequences of your interpretation are? I am not seeing any and it makes the question seem null. I am most likely wrong as I am heavily confused. I think it is interpreted the other way because that appears to be the only way of making a sensible question. I mean, Jacobson (the author) even puts a definition of bijections in terms identical to what the other interpretation says:
"$S\overset{\alpha}{\to}T$ is bijective if and only if there exists a map $T\overset{\beta}{\to}S$ such that $\beta\alpha=1_S$ and $\alpha\beta=1_T$."

Comment: Jacobson (in my opinion) is not the clearest author, and I've also found understanding exactly what he means a tad challenging (frustrating?)    Do you want to take this into a chat room?  It may be quicker and easier there.

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and create the chatroom; I can't seem to find the button.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6879/room-for-ake-and-limitless

Comment: [Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6879?m=7446425#7446425) resolving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Central Matter

With the help of Assad Ebrahim, I was able to figure out what's being said here. The crux is this:
$$
\beta \text{ is unique} \iff |S|=|T| \iff \alpha \text{ is bijective},
$$
which quickly implies that if $\alpha$ is bijective in either case.

## Elaboration and Specifics

For the mapping $\alpha$ wherein $\beta\alpha=1_S$, we have that $\alpha$ is injective. However, $\beta$ can be any map $T\to S$ such that *all* the elements of $T$ map to $S$. This means that $\beta$ acts not just on the elements $\alpha(s)$; it acts on *all* elements of $T$. As a result, there are, in general, elements in $T$ which can be mapped to *any* $s\in S$. Thus, there are many possible maps $\beta$; we can create a new one simply by changing what a given $t\in T$ which is not $\alpha(s)$ maps to.

Now, the issue is this: We are supposing $\beta$ is unique. This means there cannot be elements in $T$ which are not equal to $\alpha(s)$. If there were, then $\beta$ would cease to be unique for the reason outlined just above. Hence, we have that $\alpha$ is also surjective. Therefore, $\alpha$ is bijective. $\blacksquare$

For the mapping $\alpha$ wherein $\alpha\beta=1_T$, we have a similar situation. Using the same line of logic, we see that there cannot be $s\in S$ such that $s\ne \beta(t) $. If there were, $\beta$ would cease to be unique. Thus, we have that $\alpha$ is injective. Therefore, $\alpha$ is bijective. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Hint: You might want to start with extreme cases, such as when $S$ or $T$, but not both, has only one element.  (I take the problems to be whether "$\alpha$ is bijective if and only if there is a unique map $\beta$ such that $\beta\alpha=1_S$" and similarly for the other part.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a very good point. This question has indeed taught me to examine cases in particular detail.

Comment: If $S=\{s\}$ (a singleton) then there is exactly one map $\beta:T\rightarrow S$ (so it is unique) and $\beta\alpha=1_S$. If $T$ contains other elements next to $\alpha(s)$ (wich is the case if $T$ is not a singleton) then $\alpha$ is not surjective. So uniqueness of $\beta$ does *not* imply that $\alpha$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta:T\rightarrow S$ exists with $\beta\alpha=id_{S}$ then
we find easily that $\alpha\left(s\right)=\alpha\left(s'\right)$
implies that $s=\beta\alpha\left(s\right)=\beta\alpha\left(s'\right)=s'$
showing that $\alpha$ is injective.

Conversely let $\alpha:S\rightarrow T$
be injective. If $s_{0}\in S$ then we can construct $\beta:T\rightarrow S$
by sending each element $t=\alpha\left(s\right)\in\alpha\left(S\right)$
to the unique $t\in T$. Elements not contained in $\alpha\left(S\right)$
can be sent to $s_{0}$. Then $\beta\alpha=id_{S}$. Note however
that this does not have to work if $S=\emptyset$. We have the unique empty
map $\alpha:\emptyset\rightarrow T$ wich is vacuously injective.
Only if also $T=\emptyset$ then there exist the empty map $\beta:T=\emptyset\rightarrow\emptyset$
and indeed $\beta\alpha=id_{\emptyset}$. However, if $T\ne\emptyset$ then
no map $\beta:T\rightarrow\emptyset$ exists.

So the statement: if
$\alpha:S\rightarrow T$ is injective then $\beta\alpha=id_{S}$ for
some $\beta:T\rightarrow S$, **is true under the extra condition that**
$S\ne\emptyset\vee T=\emptyset$.

If $S$ is a singleton then automatically
$\beta$ is unique. However, if moreover $T$ is not a singleton then
$\alpha$ is not a bijection. So **uniqueness of** $\beta$ **does not imply
that** $\alpha$ **is bijective**. For this we need the extra condition that $S$ is no singleton or $T$ is a singleton.

---

If $\alpha\beta=id_{T}$ then $t=\alpha\left(\beta\left(t\right)\right)$
for each $t\in T$ showing immediately that $\alpha$ is surjective.

Conversely let $\alpha:S\rightarrow T$ be surjective. Then we construct
$\beta:T\rightarrow S$ by sending each element $t$ by one of an
elements $s\in S$ that suffices $\alpha\left(s\right)=t$. Then automatically
$\alpha\beta=id_{T}$. Note that this equation implies that $\beta(t)$ belongs to fibre $\alpha^{-1}\left(\left\{ t\right\} \right)$, so that is necessary.

If this $\beta$ with $\alpha\beta=id_{T}$ is unique
then for each $t\in T$ the fibre $\alpha^{-1}\left(\left\{ t\right\} \right)$
contains exactly one element. This tells us that the surjective $\alpha$
is also injective, hence bijective.

---

In category **Sets** every epimorphism (surjection) is a retraction (second case), but not every monomorphism (injection) is a section (first case). Exceptions are the elements in $\mathbf{Sets}\left(\emptyset,T\right)$ where $T\ne\emptyset$. They are injective but are not sections.

I have been working with sets. If you are working in groups, rings, et cetera then the underlying sets will not be empty.